# How should i maintain session of state after selecting from dropdown list?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am creating website in which after selecting state from the index page it will same for all page if I am moving from one page to another. I am fetching data in dropdown list and keep this in top right corner of web site.but  I am confuse when i select state and move to second page it change again it ask for select state. Plz tell me how should i store state in session and how to access in all page.

controller:

```
  public function getState()
    {
        $state=\App\State::all();
        return view('index',compact('state'));
    }
```

and all page contain state:

```
 <div class="selectregion">
                <br>
                <select style="margin-left:10px;" class="show-tick form-control" name ="state" id="state">
                <option value="">Select State</option>
                 @foreach($state as $state_name )
                <option value="{{ $state_name->state_id }}">{{ $state_name->state_name }}</option>
                 @endforeach                                

                </select>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save state value, you should set session when select value is changed.

So I suggest create select's `onchange` event.

#### Sample Code

**JS**

```
// send state value to controller
$('select[name="state"]').on('change', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '<url>',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            state: $('select[name="state"]').val()
        }
    })
});
```

**Controller**

```php
// For set session value
public funcion status() 
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'state' => 'required', // add some other validate
    ]);
    session(['state' => $data['state']]);
}
```

**View**

```
<select name ="state">
    <option value="">Select State</option>
    @foreach($state as $state_name )
        <option value="{{ $state_name->state_id }}" selected="{{ session('state') == $state_name->state_id ? 'true' : 'false' }}">
            {{ $state_name->state_name }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```